# SOA and WCF design questions: Is this an unusual system design?

Tags: wcf, soa

I have found myself responsible for carrying on the development of a system which I did not originally design and can't ask the original designers why certain design decisions were taken, as they are no longer here.  I am a junior developer on design issues so didn't really know what to ask when I started on the project which was my first SOA / WCF project.

The system has 7 WCF services, will grow to 9, each self-hosted in a seperate console app/windows service.  All of them are single instance and single threaded. All services have the same OperationContract: they expose a Register() and Send() method. When client services want to connect to another service, they first call Register(), then if successful they do *all* the rest of their communication with Send(). We have a DataContract that has an enum MessageType and a Content propety which can contain other DataContract "payloads." What the service does with the message is determined by the enum MessageType...everything comes through the Send() method and then gets routed to a switch statement...I suspect this is unusual

Register() and Send() are actually OneWay and Async...ALL results from services are returned to client services by a WCF CallbackContract. I believe that the reson for using CallbackContracts is to facilitate the Publish-Subscribe model we are using. The problem is not all of our communication fits publish-subscribe and using CallbackContracts means we have to include source details in returned result messages so clients can work out what the returned results were originally for...again clients have a switch statements to work out what to do with messages arriving from services based on the MessageType (and other embedded details).

In terms of topology: the services form "nodes" in a graph. Each service has hardcoded a list of other services it must connect to when it starts, and wont allow client services to "Register" with it until is has made all of the connections it needs. As an example, we have a LoggingService and a DataAccessService. The DataAccessSevice is a client of the LoggingService and so the DataAccess service will attempt to Register with the LoggingService when it starts. Until it can successfully Register the DataAccess service will not allow any clients to Register with it. The result is that when the system is fired up as a whole the services start up in a cascadeing manner. I don't see this as an issue, but is this unusual?

To make matters more complex, one of the systems requirements is that services or "nodes" do not need to be directly registered with one another in order to send messages to one another, but can communicate via indirect links. For example, say we have 3 services A, B and C connected in a chain, A can send a message to C *via* B...using 2 hops.

I was actually tasked with this and wrote the routing system, it was fun, but the lead left before I could ask why it was really needed. As far as I can see, there is no reason why services cannot just connect direct to the other services they need. Whats more I had to write a reliability system on top of everything as the requirement was to have reliable messaging *across* nodes in the system, wheras with simple point-to-point links WCF reliabily does the job.

Prior to this project I had only worked on winforms desktop apps for 3 years, do didn't know any better. My suspicions are things are overcomplicated with this project: I guess to summarise, my questions are:

1) Is this idea of a graph topology with messages hopping over indirect links unusual? Why not just connect services directly to the services that they need to access (which in reality is what we do anyway...I dont think we have any messages hopping)?

2) Is exposing just 2 methods in the OperationContract and using the a MessageType enum to determine what the message is for/what to do with it unusual? Shouldnt a WCF service expose lots of methods with specific purposes instead and the client chooses what methods it wants to call?

3) Is doing all communication back to a client via CallbackContracts unusual. Surely sync or asyc request-response is simpler.

4) Is the idea of a service not allowing client services to connect to it (Register) until it has connected to all of its services (to which it is a client) a sound design? I think this is the only design aspect I agree with, I mean the DataAccessService should not accept clients until it has a connection with the logging service.

I have so many WCF questions, more will come in later threads. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, the whole things seems a bit odd, agreed.

> All of them are single instance and
>   single threaded.

That's definitely going to come back and cause massive performance headaches - guaranteed. I don't understand why anyone would want to write a singleton WCF service to begin with (except for a few edge cases, where it does make sense), and if you do have a singleton WCF service, to get any decent performance, it must be multi-threaded (which is tricky programming, and is why I almost always advise against it).

> All services have the same
>   OperationContract: they expose a
>   Register() and Send() method.

That's rather odd, too. So anyone calling will first .Register(), and then call .Send() with different parameters several times?? Funny design, really.... The SOA assumption is that you design your services to be the model of a set of functionality you want to expose to the outside world, e.g. your `CustomerService` might have methods like `GetCustomerByID`, `GetAllCustomersByCountry`, etc. methods - depending on what you need.

Having just a single Send() method with parameters which define what is being done seems a bit.... unusual and not very intuitive / clear.

> Is this idea of a graph topology with
>   messages hopping over indirect links
>   unusual?

Not necessarily. It can make sense to expose just a single interface to the outside world, and then use some internal backend services to do the actual work. .NET 4 will actually introduce a [RoutingService in WCF](http://weblogs.thinktecture.com/cweyer/2009/05/whats-new-in-wcf4-routing-service---or-look-ma-just-one-service-to-talk-to.html) which makes these kind of scenarios easier. I don't think this is a big no-no.

> Is doing all communication back to a
>   client via CallbackContracts unusual.

Yes, unusual, fragile, messy - if you can ever do without it - go for it. If you have mostly simple calls, like `GetCustomerByID` - make those a standard Request/Response call - the client requests something (by supplying a Customer ID) and gets back a `Customer` object as a return value. Much much simpler!

If you do have long-running service calls, that might take minutes or more to complete - then you might consider One-Way calls which just deposit a request into a queue, and that request gets handled later on. Typically, here, you can either deposit the answer into a response queue which the client then checks, or you can have two additional service methods which give you the status of a request (is it done yet?) and a second method to retrieve the result(s) of that request.

Hope that helps to get you started !

Comment: The Send() method takes an ActionMessage DataContract, which has a string Destination field used for routing to a destination, and a reference to another DataContract type as payload. The payload DataContracts all inherit from a base type which has a MessageContentType enum field, and it is this that services use to determine if they are intrested in data processing passing through them before they route the message on. The Destination string can specify what service node types you want the message to pass through.

Thanks for the information. Ill mark as answer after a few other replies.

Comment: I should add that we do have a SessionManagerService which is the "gateway" into the system for our Silverlight clients. Originally they did send messages to backend services via this one gateway (using its Send() method) which routed messages on to the correct backend service and routed messages back to the correct browser client instance from those services. Now, however, this isnt the case, seperate messages are used between Clients <> SessionManager <> BackEndServices, so eveything is single hop. The SessionManager actually retains the UI state and "pushes" this to the Silverlight clients.

Answer (score 5):

> All services have the same OperationContract: they expose a Register() and Send() method.

Your design seems unusual at some parts specially exposing only two operations. I haven't worked with WCF, we use Java. But based on my understanding the whole purpose of Web Services is to expose Operations that your partners can utilise.
Having only two Operations looks like odd design to me. You generally expose your API using WSDL. In this case the WSDL would add nothing of value to the partners, unless you have lot of documentation. Generally the operation name should be self-explanatory. Right now your system cannot be used by partners without having internal knowledge.

> Is doing all communication back to a client via CallbackContracts unusual. Surely sync or asyc request-response is simpler.

Agree with you. Async should only be used for long running processes. Async adds the overhead of correlation.